# Runtime check for validity of function pointer array pointer to function pointers with different arguments

Tags: c, function-pointers

I have implemented a function pointer array like so:

```
// functions to point to
void foo1 (void) {}; 
void foo2 (char * str) {}; 
void foo3 (char * str1, char * str2) {};

//enum used for indexing
enum fp{
    loc1 = 0,
    loc2,
    loc3,
    size 
};

typedef union {
    void (*) (void);
    void (*) (char *);
    void (*) (char *, char *);        
} genericfp_t;

genericfp_t myArray[size] = {foo1, foo2, foo3};
```

In my code I will be strictly using the enum to call the function pointer array: (eg)

```
myArray[loc1]();
myArray[loc2]('1');
```

It has been pointed out to me that this is still bad practice in terms of code safety. They argued on the eventuality that someone could use some variable which changes during runtime to call the array and could end up with a situation as illustrated below:

```
int index = 0;

myArray[index]('1'); // inconsistent
```

What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: Your code is not compilable.

Comment: Honestly, a design "pattern" like this makes the hair on the back of my neck a bit twitchy...

Comment: I'm wondering... why?